# What kind of vegetable oil should I use for baking?

Tags: baking, cake, oil

I'm going to bake this cake: http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/French-Yogurt-Cake-395471
and was wondering what sort of vegetable oil (canola etc) I should use? Would the type of oil make any difference to the cake?

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/28131/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/31982/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/670/67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of oil you use in baking is mostly a matter of personal preference.  Any neutral oil (no strong flavor) will do.

I suggest you use an oil that you keep around for another purpose, which is not too expensive.

Some good candidates include:

- Canola oil
- Peanut oil (refined, except for those with peanut allergies)
- Generic "vegetable" oil

Grapeseed oil is also excellent but tends to expensive.

Oils you would want to avoid due to the fact that they bring more flavor which may not be what you want in baked goods include:

- Olive oil
- Sesame oil
- Unrefined oils of all sorts

Comment: To put this another way, the whole reason they just say "vegetable oil" without being more specific is that it doesn't really matter which neutral oil you use.

Comment: Corn oil is another commonly available 'neutral' oil.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend canola oil when I'm required to use oil, but I recommend using butter instead it taste more homemade.